# Are browser credentials resubmitted when a javascript fetch redirects?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Assume a javascript fetch is made like this:

```
fetch('https://example.com', {
  credentials: 'include',
  redirect: 'follow'
});
```

If the URL returns a redirect (and the redirect itself might further redirect), are the browser's credentials resubmitted in further requests in that chain of follow requests?

Comment: As the redirect happens on the target server, it is up to the URL to pass on whatever credentials it has received.

Comment: Did you try it to see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

They are not "submitted". They are included based on the request URL. And yes, that applies to each individual request, but the credentials that end up being included can differ.